# How to correctly expose a docker server with ngrok?

Tags: docker, ngrok

I have a docker installation running on my machine and I can access the site on my browser by going to `mysite.local` (defined to map to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file)

When I run `ngrok http mysite.local` it works fine but when I open the http://random_id.ngrok.io link

- ngrok console shows:

> GET /                          301 Moved Permanently

- I get a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error and If I click on **advanced->proceed to... http://random_id.ngrok.io (unsafe)**, it just shows

> Tunnel [www.random_id.ngrok.io](http://www.random_id.ngrok.io) not found

Worth nothing this rule in `.htaccess` even though it looks fine to me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.local
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE** `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite mysite.local` seems indeed to work but:
css and oher assets fail to load (the only css-related rule in .htaccess is: `AddType text/css .chunk.css AddType text/css .css`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the rewrite rule *is* the issue to me.

Your rule states:

> If the http host does **not** start with `mysite.local`,
>   then redirect to `https://www.HOST/[...]`

I'd recommend either removing the rewrite rule entirely *or* use ngrok's [http host header rewrite](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-host-header) functionality:

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite mysite.local
```

Comment: it indeed seems to work. however css and oher assets fail to load (the only css-related rule in .htaccess is: AddType text/css .chunk.css AddType text/css .css)